# Having trouble assigning a list variable to SSM Parameter as a stringList

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, aws-ssm

I receive an error, value must be a string, when trying to set an ssm parameter with type=stringlist to a variable of type list using terraform.

```
    resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "customer_list_stg" {
      name = "/corp/stg/customer_list"
      type = "StringList"
      value = var.customer_list

      tags = {
        environment = var.environment
      }
    }


customer_list = ["sar", "smi", "heath","first","human","stars","ther","ugg","stars","well"]
```

```
terraform apply: expecting an ssm parameter with a list of 10 strings

received an error: Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required.
```

I have tried `tostring`, `jsonencode` and `flatten` without success.

Answer (score 0):

Just use list as the type, StringList isn't a valid HCL type.  Please see the documentation here:
[https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types][1]

Comment: type is an argument on the aws_ssm_parameter resource where "StringList" is a valid value :) .  ref : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssm_parameter#type  and the `customer_list` is a valid list(sting) type but the issue is with `value` argument input.

Comment: I was using the original given information for my answer.  Given teh data he was trying to attach to the variable, a list of strings was appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the attribute `type = "StringList"`, the `value` attribute of `aws_ssm_parameter` always expects a string literal.

Please refer to the [AWS API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_Parameter.html)

Hence the correct code would be as follow

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "customer_list_stg" {
  name = "/corp/stg/customer_list"
  type = "StringList"
  value = join(",", var.customer_list) ## if you want to use list(string) input

  # value = "sar,smi,heath,first,human,stars,ther,ugg,stars,well" ## as a string literal (you can put this value in a variable too)


  tags = {
    environment = var.environment # define this variable in your config too.
  }
}


variable "customer_list" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "(optional) Customer List"
  default     = ["sar", "smi", "heath", "first", "human", "stars", "ther", "ugg", "stars", "well"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 

We were able to get it to work wrapping var.customer_list in jsonencode and changing the variable declaration to list(string) also.